# Multiple ASCX User Controls: How do I access the values of each instance?

Tags: asp.net, ascx, clientid

I am still using ASP 3.5.  I have an ASP User Control:

```
*<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="GuideList.ascx.cs" Inherits="GuideList" %>

    <asp:DropDownList ID="GL" ClientIDMode="AutoID" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>Adam</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Amanda</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Bruce</asp:ListItem>
    ...
    </asp:DropDownList>*
```

This control is placed on an ASPX page several times:

*

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="main" Runat="Server">
    ...
    <p>First Guide <br />
    <uc3:GuideList ID="GuideList1" runat="server" />
    ...
    <p>Second Guide <br />
    <uc3:GuideList ID="GuideList2" runat="server" />
    ...
    <p>Third Guide <br />
    <uc3:GuideList ID="GuideList3" runat="server" />
    etc.
</asp:Content>
```

*

When I view the source of this page, I see the first instance of the control as:

```
<select name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$main$GuideList1$GL" id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_main_GuideList1_GL" ClientIDMode="AutoID">
```

How do I reference each of these Drop Down Box Controls by ID in the Button1_Click event of this page?  None of the following work:

```
msg.Body = msg.Body + ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$main$GuideList1$GL.Text.Trim() + "<br />"
msg.Body = msg.Body + ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_main_GuideList1_GL.Text.Trim() + "<br />"
msg.Body = msg.Body + GL.Text.Trim() + "<br />"
msg.Body = msg.Body + <%= GL.ClientID %>.Text.Trim() + "<br />"
msg.Body = msg.Body + <%= ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_main_GuideList1_GL.ClientID %>.Text.Trim() + "<br />"
msg.Body = msg.Body + <%= ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$main$GuideList1$GL.ClientID %>.Text.Trim() + "<br />"
```

I have only tried using AutoID, but I control all the code so I don't mind specifying controls explicitly.

Anyway, can anyone help me solve this mysterious riddle?  From the web examples I see, it seems like Javascript works fine with the IDs above, just not the VB.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Steve